# Finding the difference within a SQL Server query and dividing by seconds elapsed between records

Tags: sql-server, coalesce, rate

Hi I have a table of meter values in a SQL Server database, which contains a table with the following columns:

```
Timestamp, meterID, rawValue
```

I am trying to graph the water usage rate using a query and google charts, the problem is that I need to calculate the rate from the raw meter values which are updated every 15 to 30 minutes.

I want to run a query that returns the values for a specific water meter.

```
MeterID, Timestamp, (rawValue-previousRawValue)/(timestamp difference in seconds)
```

any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Do you use SQL Server 2000 or 2005/8 ?

Answer (score 0):

I made a few minor changes to both my query and @Bogdan's query to make them as similar as possible, then compared them. Bogdan's modified query is at the bottom of this post.

Stacked together in the same query, according to the SQL Server Query Execution Plan, mine is 53% of the query cost, and Bogdan's is 47%.

For the data set offered in the Bogdan's post:

- My query: 6 scans and 27 logical reads
- Bogdan's: 6 scans and 72 logical reads

I added values every 15secs up to 5mins for both meterID 1 and 2, for a total of 42 records, then reran the queries with SQL Server Profiler.

Where my query wins on reads, Bogdan's still wins on CPU and Duration.

```
          CPU  SCANS  READS  DURATION
--------------------------------------
Mine       47     22    313     249ms
Bogdan's   16     22    972      15ms
--------------------------------------
```

---

I'm making a few assumptions, like that your MeterID is an INT. Change that as necessary.

I'm also assuming since you want to run the query for a specific meter ID, that it will be passed in as a parameter to a stored procedure.

This should work on SQL Server 2005 and later.

I do a few things that might distract from the actual solution. The core logic is really within the WHILE loop.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetMeterResults]
    @MeterID INT
AS
BEGIN

    -- create a temp table to store results
    CREATE TABLE #tempResults
    (
        MeterID INT,
        [Timestamp] DATETIME,
        Result FLOAT
    )

    DECLARE  
        @Timestamp DATETIME, 
        @RawValue INT,
        @LastTimestamp DATETIME, 
        @LastRawValue INT,
        @FirstRun BIT = 1

    DECLARE cr CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR 
    SELECT 
        [Timestamp], 
        RawValue 
    FROM 
        YourTable
    WHERE
        MeterID = @MeterID
    ORDER BY
        [Timestamp]

    OPEN cr
    FETCH NEXT FROM cr INTO @Timestamp, @RawValue

    WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
    BEGIN
        IF (@FirstRun = 1)
        BEGIN -- the first run
            SELECT @FirstRun = 0 -- flip the bit for all future runs
        END
        ELSE -- all subsequent runs after the first 
        BEGIN       
            INSERT INTO 
                #tempResults
            SELECT 
                @MeterID,
                @Timestamp, 
                (@RawValue - @LastRawValue) * 1.00 / DATEDIFF(s, @LastTimestamp, @Timestamp)
        END

            -- save the current values for comparison on the next run       
        SELECT  
            @LastTimestamp = @Timestamp, 
            @LastRawValue = @RawValue

        FETCH NEXT FROM cr INTO @Timestamp, @RawValue
    END

    CLOSE CR
    DEALLOCATE CR

    -- return the result set
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        #tempResults

    -- clean up the temp table
    DROP TABLE #tempResults
END
GO
```

---

Bogdan's modified query that filters by MeterID for an apples-to-apples comparison with my query above:

```
DECLARE @MeterID INT = 1;

WITH ValuesWithRowNumber
AS
(
    SELECT  mv.MeterID
            ,mv.RawValue
            ,mv.[Timestamp]
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY mv.MeterID ORDER BY mv.[Timestamp] ASC) RowNum
    FROM    dbo.MeterValues mv
    WHERE mv.MeterID = @MeterID
)
SELECT  crt.MeterID
        ,crt.[Timestamp] AS CrtTimestamp
        ,prev.[Timestamp] AS PrevTimestamp
        ,crt.RawValue AS CrtRawValue
        ,prev.RawValue AS PrevRawValue
        ,(crt.RawValue - prev.RawValue)*1.00/DATEDIFF(SECOND, prev.[Timestamp], crt.[Timestamp]) Diff
FROM    ValuesWithRowNumber crt --crt=current
JOIN ValuesWithRowNumber prev ON crt.RowNum - 1 = prev.RowNum
ORDER BY crt.[Timestamp];
```

Comment: `FORWARD_ONLY FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY` ? [FAST_FORWARD = FORWARD_ONLY + READ_ONLY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx)

Comment: Did you used IUN_MeterValues_MeterID_Timestamp index for testing ?

Comment: Yep - I used your CREATE TABLE and INDEX statements just as you posted them. I simply omitted the DDL from my post. Just out of curiosity, I will retest with your index changes.

Comment: I have modified `IUN_MeterValues_MeterID_Timestamp` index so `Bookmark Lookup` operator will be eliminated. This means less logical reads. Also I have added another solution based on "quirky update" method.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this

Select a.metered,a.timestamp,
   (a.rawValue-b.rawValue)/(a.timestamp-b.timestamp)

From meters A
Join (selec top 2 rawValue,Timestamp 
      From meters where metered = @meter
      order by timestamp DESC) b
On b.timestamp <> a.timestamp and a.meterId=B.meterId
```

Added a DESC to the timestamp in the middle query.  This will cause the most recent two timestamps to be returned, and then the JOIN will "filter out" the one that matches the current row from A

Comment: You're comparing each new value to the same first value, then calculating the rate of change for each value since the beginning. I believe @tbrew wants to compare each value to the immediately previous value, and calculate rate of change only since the previous value. Also, I think you join Row 1 with Row 2, then join Row 2 with Row 1. The latter will give you a stray, opposite result from the former.  Don't get me wrong, I like your solution, and I like especially that it's a set operation instead of a cursor, I'm just not sure it satisfies the requirements.

Comment: Re: your update, now you're calculating the rate of change for all values from the point in time of the value, to the most recent point in time. That's, again, not comparing each value to the previous value.